# How to get array value from looping in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i think this is a simple problem. but i can't finish  it. Please help me to do this simple problem. I want to get values from array use looping.
and this is my code

```
<?for ($i = 1 ; $i <=5 ; $i++){
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo $foo[i];
}
?>
```

It doesn't work :(

Comment: You should use $i not i

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo $foo[$i];
```

You missed $ before i it should be $i to mark it variable.

Comment: Whoa~ You're right! Thank you..

Comment: mark the answer as the accepted answer, please

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
<?php

   $foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);  
   $max = count($foo);

   for ($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++) {
      echo $foo[$i];
   }

?>
```

Remember to use the `$` before every variable in PHP.

**Advice**: Set a variable with the count of array's items to use in the loop.

**Note**: the array is declared before the loop, otherwise it will recreate it each time.

**Note 2**: initialize `$i` with `0`, otherwise you will miss the first element of the array.

Comment: i think `for ($i = 1 ; $i < $max ; $i++) {` should be changed to `for ($i = 0 ; $i < $max-1 ; $i++) {`. Remember, array index starts from zero

Comment: like this you'd miss the last element

Comment: don't forget to change `$max` to `$max-1`, or the loop will "get an extra offset"

Comment: you don't need `$max-1` if using `<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
for ($i = 1 ; $i <=5 ; $i++){
echo $foo[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: You missed the $i in your echo statement.

Comment: That was a mistake an i corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You may also change the setting for loop statement, start from 0 and end before 5. Index for array starts on 0

```
    <?for ($i = 0 ; $i <5 ; $i++){
    $foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    echo $foo[$i];
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach ($foo as $value) {
    echo "value: ".$value;
}
```

If you want to know the index of the current value you can use:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($foo as $index=>$value) {
    echo "index: ".$index." value: ".$value;
}
```

The advantage of using **foreach** is that it takes care about the size of your array and iterates through all elements with step 1. If you need iterate with the different step(let's say +2 or +3) you have to use the standard **for** loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   $foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
   for ($i = 1 ; $i <=5 ; $i++)
   {
      echo $foo[$i];
   }
?>
```

PHP needs to have an open tag like this `<?php`

Place `$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);` outside the loop.

Added the `$` to `echo $foo[$i];`